# AES encryption, sample code

Tags: encryption, aes

How do I go about performing AES encryption on a GUID?

On the clients computer we will store a GUID and their public key, and our internal servers will have the private key and their guid.

Is this all the necessary inputs to generate the AES encryption?

Answer (score 8):

[AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) is a symmetric encryption algorithm (encrypt and decrypt key is the same). If you are talking about public and private keys, you want an [asymmetric encryption algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) such as RSA.

Comment: Methinks he's using PKI for client-server interaction and needs to store the associated public and private keys.  Although not exactly standard practice in this situation, AES is a reasonable way to protect the PKI keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt anything that can be represented as a stream of bytes.  The only ingredient missing from the  "recipe" in your question is the encryption key:

```
void encrypt(char *plaintext, char *key, char *crypt)
{
  // Encrypt plaintext with the key, returning the result in crypt.

}
```

**Notes:**

- Using PKI (public/private keys), each participant typically maintains its own *private* key in a secure manner and freely distributes its *public* key.  Messages are encrypted using the *public* key of the *recipient* and decrypted by each recipient with the *private* key.  From the phrasing of the question, it's not apparent that you're using this model.
- Jesse provides a good example for demonstration purposes.  Just remember that you probably do *not* want to hard-code keys in your production application..

Comment: Agreed - if your code leaves your secure boundaries (i.e. your managed server), you should be looking at a public key infrastructure solution.  If it is completely contained, store your keys in a database so that if the server with the code is compromised, you're still in the clear.

Comment: But you _don't_ want to be in the clear -- that's why we're encrypting in the first place!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick encrypt/decrypt of string data using AES (Rijndael):

```
private static readonly byte[] rgbKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Ni=9OE=$i+62eprIuDr@ewOu5I9r34Ro"); // change to your own secure key

private static readonly byte[] rgbIv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("to$eO_e!maI*o3ut"); // change to your own secure initialization vector

public static string Encrypt(string originalString)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(originalString))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(
           "originalString",
           "The string which needs to be encrypted can not be null.");
    }

    using (var cryptoProvider = new RijndaelManaged())
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var encryptor = cryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor(rgbKey, rgbIv))
    using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
    {
        writer.Write(originalString);
        writer.Flush();
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        writer.Flush();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
    }
}

public static string Decrypt(string encryptedString)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(encryptedString))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(
           "encryptedString",
           "The string which needs to be decrypted can not be null.");
    }

    using (var cryptoProvider = new RijndaelManaged())
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedString)))
    using (var decryptor = cryptoProvider.CreateDecryptor(rgbKey, rgbIv))
    using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream))
    {
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the default CipherMode?

Comment: Cipher-Block Chaining.  As far as I can tell, this is the default for all SymmetricAlgorithm descendants.